# How do you allow duplicate CSS properties using Sass Lint?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, lint, gulp-sass

I am trying to allow duplicate CSS properties in my scss file I am using gulp and lint-scss

My current class is

```
    .alink {
        color: #0059a1;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: -webkit-fit-content;
        height: -moz-fit-content;
        height: fit-content;

    }
```

My current settings in my YAML file (sass-lint.yml) has a setting of `no-duplicate-properties: 1`  My settings in lint-scss.js is `'no-duplicate-properties': 1,` How do you change the settings in these files to allow duplicate CSS properties

Comment: `no-duplicate-properties: 0`?

Comment: @EternalHour Thanks have you tried it before? I wanted to know before I do a full build. I figured that was it

Comment: I haven't tried it before but seems like a logical possibility.

Comment: Sounds like your life would be easier overall just enabling PostCSS Autoprefixer and not worry about doing the prefixes yourself. :D

Comment: Just use `fit-content` directly. IE doesn't support it anyway, and you're only gaining a `0.6%` browser share by bothering with the prefixes (exclusive to older versions of Safari).

Comment: @ObsidianAge I know this is just one example but I have multiple examples where duplicate CSS properties are needed